# What D&D-style fantasy book had a bag of holding with an entire world inside it?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in high school ('88-'91) and I'm trying to find the title of the book.  It was a fantasy book along the lines of D&D and all I remember about the book was a bag of holding that had an entire world inside it. I want to say they even smuggled an army inside the bag.

I know that isn't a lot of info but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the cover art work?

Comment: Any of the books listed in the Lit section of [TVTropes' **Bag of Holding** article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BagOfHolding) sound familar?

Comment: The part about an army being smuggled reminded me of the magic bottles used in the Chronicles of an Age of Darkness series by Hugh Cook. The bottles have tower like cities inside them with numerous levels but not entire worlds

Answer (score 9):

Possibly [Nightwings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightwings)(1968), by Robert Silverberg.

Nightwings is the first in a trilogy of novellas, the next two being Perris Way (1968) and To Jorslem (1969). These three works were later collected into a single novel in three sections, also titled Nightwings.

Plot Summary:

> In a decadent and caste-based future, humanity is divided into guilds,
>   each having a specific job to do. The members of some guilds appear to
>   have undergone genetic engineering, for instance, the Fliers' ability
>   to fly and the Watchers' ability to use their mental capabilities to
>   watch distant stars.
>
> The main character in the novella is a Watcher whose mission is to
>   watch the skies with some sophisticated equipment and to inform the
>   Defenders in the event of an alien invasion. Along with a young Flier
>   girl and a Changeling (who belongs to no guild), he visits the old
>   city of Roum (suspected previously to be called Rome), and becomes
>   entangled in events including the possibility of invasion.
>
> Apart from Roum, only two other great cities are mentioned, Jorslem
>   (Jerusalem) and Perris (Paris), but their greatness is relative, as
>   they only have a few thousand inhabitants.

Bit more Sci-Fi than fantasy, but it does have an item called an "overpocket" which

> "...was infinitely capacious; the contents of a world, if need be, could
>   be stuffed into its shriveled gray maw, and still it would be no
>   longer than a man's hand. Gormon took from it bits of machinery,
>   reading spools, an angular thing of brown metal that might have been
>   an ancient tool, three squares of shining glass, five slips of
>   paper—paper!—and a host of other relics of antiquity."

~from [Google Books' excerpt of the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=H2M0Ad8IHOoC&pg=PT17&lpg=PT17&dq=robert%20silverberg%20nightwings%20overpocket&source=bl&ots=_2VApGCp_t&sig=--IYa_Vrx9lj3SMrwytZcXNgiFo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M3e2VN6QIIuegwTwpYPQAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=robert%20silverberg%20nightwings%20overpocket&f=false).