Story which includes the Prince of Roum
"The Prince of Roum gave me more pleasure than anyone else, but he was cruel." Teratogenic heralds bellowed "make way for the Prince of Roum!"

The heralds were teratogenic? You mean they caused developmental anomalies? How did they do that? They were radioactive, or they exuded chemicals, or what?

Their vocal capabilities had been amplified. They are human loudspeakers.

And that makes them teratogenic? Pregnant women who hear their amplified voices give birth to deformed children?

They had been altered in shape and function. They were squat and broad, and their voices were extremely loud. They themselves were not teratogenic, but they had been created, I suppose, by teratogenic means.

"Make way for the Prince of Roum!" is a quote from Robert Silverberg's Nightwings.
So is "The Prince of Roum gave me greater pleasure of the body than I had ever known before, but he is cold and cruel..."
Given the sparseness of the question, there is not much more to say.
The novella can be read on Archive.org; it was later fixed-up with two sequels into a novel.

That was the story I sought. Thank you.

Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233271/novel-where-earth-has-a-caste-system/233274#233274 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79158/what-dd-style-fantasy-book-had-a-bag-of-holding-with-an-entire-world-inside-it/79170#79170
